# Spark application UI becomes unavailable

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ui

Apache Spark is deployed via bitnami helm chart on Kubernetes. The reverse Proxy for the UI is enabled and working fine (except for some dead links / rewrites). After running fine for a while, the application detail UI becomes unavailable and shows only:

`HTTP ERROR 502 Bad Gateway URI: /proxy/app-20230505142116-0000 STATUS: 502  MESSAGE: Bad Gateway  SERVLET: org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anon$3-3d29ecc5 Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.48.v20220622`

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? The application itself keeps running without an error and finishes successfully.